# backup a sqlite database. transferTo and transferFrom not working

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

i try to backup my app database by copy it to external. i try this code below but didn't work.

```
backupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                String state =  Environment.getExternalStorageState();
                String mounted = Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED;
                if (mounted.equals(state)) {
                    File currentDB = context.getDatabasePath(DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_NAME);
                    File backupDB = new File(sd, "backupTester.db");

                    if (currentDB.exists()) {
                        FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                        FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                        src.transferTo(0,src.size(),dst);
                        src.close();
                        dst.close();
                        Toast.makeText(context, "DB EXPORTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                else Toast.makeText(context, "No SD Card", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "backup not running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: have you tried with `dst.flush()` before `dst.close`?

Comment: @MikeT I can't apply that method. Can you show me how to apply it ?

Comment: You could use if you had :- `FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(backupDB);
                        FileChannel src = fos.getChannel();
                        FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                        src.transferTo(0,src.size(),dst);
                        src.close();
                        fos.flush();
                        dst.close();`. However I'll post answer showing how I copy a DB (at least the core)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer, that code doesn't work because the storage permission on the apps not turned on. It happen on android version 5++

Turn on the storage permission on the device or virtual device.

Application Manager->{Your App Name}-> Permissions -> Storage

Answer (score 0):

This is working code (at least the core code) of how I create a DB copy :-

```
            try {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dbfile);
                OutputStream backup = new FileOutputStream(backupfilename);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
                int length;
                while((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    backup.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                backup.flush();
                backup.close();
                fis.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: it still not working for me. I think i have an error on my FileOutputStream. Can you help me figure it out ? Is the path that i use is wrong ? Why you use 32768 instead of 1024 ?

Comment: 1024 would be fine, but 32k might be more efficient (works ok for me). I assume that you've set permissions for writing to external storage.

Comment: i have use permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and still can export database

Comment: Have you read:- *Note: don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory can better be thought as media/shared storage. It is a filesystem that can hold a relatively large amount of data and that is shared across all applications (does not enforce permissions). Traditionally this is an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be mounted as a filesystem on a computer*

Comment: That is it may not have been stored on the SDCard in the slot for an SDCard (in my experience it never is), rather it's actually store in internal storage. I'd suggest add lines to Log the actual storage location. e.g. **/sdcard/Download/ShopWise/ShopWiseDB_201705010623.bkp** is actually **/storage/emulated/0/Download/ShopWise/ShopWiseDB_201705010623.bkp**

Comment: i have found the problem. Thx